# Add custom constructor to swagger generated model

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-codegen

I'm trying to add a custom constructor to a model generated by swagger, I was wondering if its possible for the model generation to be like below

example swagger model

```
@Schema(description = "Base Profile")
@javax.annotation.Generated(value = "io.swagger.codegen.v3.generators.java.JavaClientCodegen", date = "2020-10-08T18:15:35.865361-04:00[America/Vancouver]")
public class Account {
  @SerializedName("id")
  private Integer id = null;

  @SerializedName("username")
  private String username = null;

  @SerializedName("lastModified")
  private LocalDate lastModified = null;

  @SerializedName("email")
  private String email = null;

//getter setter
}
```

I need a constructor that does not contain the username and email

```
public Account(String username, String email)
```

Thanks